# How can I prolong my current Swedish visa to a permanent one after 3 years without a job but studying the local language

Tags: visa, immigration, residency, sweden

How can I extend my visa after 3 years here in Sweden without a job and being currently enrolled in a nurse assistant type of course? I came here from Brazil with my husband who got an IT job. But we divorced last year. I finished my Swedish language course on SFI, and now, as I said, am studying grund. But the migration department refused to process my application. Can someone enlighten me with regards to my current situation? I remember reading somewhere that if a person can confirm that they are enrolled in a Swedish cultural course, it can prolong their stay.

Comment: What is your current visa status? You mentioned an application - An application for what exactly? Why do you want to prolong your stay? What is 'grund'? Is that a reference to the nursing course?  It will be difficult to answer your question without some of this more basic information.

Comment: my old visa status is for a job, but i don't have one right now,  last year i started a course for nurse assistent school  been one year of studies i though that when was time to renew my visa wouldn't be such a headache,but then i discovered that i needed to be at university or studying a higher education for this visa, other option would be apply for a job visa, trying to find.....but no job success after 3 years here , so yeah, jobless, studying nothing of this currently status helped me to get a visa here in Sweden, 3 years trying to have a dissent life! I failed! Really frustrating.

Comment: What is your ex-husband's nationality?

Comment: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) says "grund" means "basic." The OP may be referring to learning Swedish.

Comment: my husband, we are from the same land , from brazil.

Comment: [migrationsverket](https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Studying-and-researching-in-Sweden/Higher-education/Residence-permit-for-higher-education.html) requires you to support yourself during studying and be learn something qualifiable. There is nothing around it unfortunately as far as I can see (not a lawyer and so on) you will need to find a job, and a job that is approvable for a job visa.